# I can select exit node, I can select entry node. Can I select middle node?

Tags: configuration

I can select exit node by `torrc` option.

I can select entry node, similar way, right?

Can I select middle node?

In other word, can I select full chain by hand in torrc?

Three fingerprints and nothing more...

```
EntryNodes fingerprint#1
? 
ExitNodes fingerprint#3
```

Comment: I have occasionally had good reason to select exit node (to get a particular country).  I cannot think of any. Practical purpose for caring where the upstream node is.

Comment: For example, to debug system. To set all your nodes as transport and watch on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can build entirely custom circuits using the control port through [EXTENDCIRCUIT](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt#n897), then attach streams to the circuits using [ATTACHSTREAM](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt#n942)

There is little real use or merit for restricting the entry, exit or middle node in some static manner through the torrc, I don't think there's an "approved" or even "good" or "consistent" way to do it, except taking ExcludeNodes and StrictNodes to ridiculous extremes. If you want to play about with custom circuits, use the control port. Stem, txtorcon, and similar libraries have helper functions for these things. Maybe have a look at how exitmap uses stem for it's circuit building.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible (and it never should be) to specify a middle node in Tor; Tor chooses it for you. 
The middle node is the best place to attack. It knows the IP address of both the entry and exit and if someone could select specific routes through the network, it might hurt your anonymity.

Comment: BUt, as I can understand the logic of p2p-tor-network. Every nodes are equal to each other. And only me, my client is choosing how to create a circuit. Is not? I mean, if it is not configurable in `torrc`, anyway it can be done by raw code, for example little patch to daemon. Is not?